# Mentioning orderer name while using kafka configuration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using orderer in kafka mode. Now while invoking chaincode, I need to supply orderer name. But then whats the use of kafka to select orderer if I need to supply the orderer name by my own.

Answer (score 0):

I'll note that the client can initialize a channel in memory that has record of multiple orderers, and the SDK should provide the option of sending your transaction via a random orderer. While one organization's client may communicate with one orderer, another organization might prefer to have its client set up to use a different orderer (or group of orderers, and perhaps these are running on the organizations own servers).

Where kafka comes in is that it's a way to provide **crash-fault tolerance** to channels with high throughput and a set up of *multiple orderers* by helping keep track of transactions and thus allowing proper sequencing of blocks. Specifically, when the client sends the transaction to an orderer, the orderer then relays to a partition that the kafka cluster maintains, and then orderers then consume/read from this partition to package transactions into blocks (orderers are both producers and consumers in this set up). kafka keeps all the orderers in sync by maintaining a stream of transactions that's used by all of them.

The full technical solution is outlined in https://docs.google.com/document/d/19JihmW-8blTzN99lAubOfseLUZqdrB6sBR0HsRgCAnY/edit, the below image is from page 11.

From the readthedocs page (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/kafka.html):

> Each channel maps to a separate single-partition topic in Kafka. When an OSN receives transactions via the Broadcast RPC, it checks to make sure that the broadcasting client has permissions to write on the channel, then relays (i.e. produces) those transactions to the appropriate partition in Kafka. This partition is also consumed by the OSN which groups the received transactions into blocks locally, persists them in its local ledger, and serves them to receiving clients via the Deliver RPC. For low-level details, refer to the document that describes how we came to this design — Figure 8 is a schematic representation of the process described above.

[image]